# CREATE action for profile missing (v3)?

Tags: api, profile

I want to create a profile but I don't see that in the action dropdown. Have attached an image
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entity is called UFGroup, and UFField for the fields. The naming is historical. The Profile entity is used to do something equivalent to filling out and submitting a profile form on the front end.